# Can't get Azure Virtual Machine to serve websites

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, hosting

I've just set up a windows azure VM and installed IIS on it.

When I remote desktop onto the box I can see the default IIS website fine but I can't get this to serve on the web from the IP address of the box.

I've opened up port 80 on windows firewall and also added an endpoint for port 80.

I've tried to access it with the firewall completely turned off also but to no avail...

I cant work out if there is anything else I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Just to clarify: When you try accessing your VM from the web, you're doing it by IP address, not by name (`http://myservice.cloudapp.net`)? Also: How did you obtain the IP address: Via `ipconfig` while RDP'd, or via the Azure portal?

Comment: Hello, 

I have been trying to access it from the PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS which is stipulated in the portal, I have also tried from the DNS name but that does not work either

Comment: You'll have to set endpoints on the VM's, for Port 80 `http` and 443 `https`. For new azure portal, you'll need to set up inbound rules. This part of video describes it https://youtu.be/5qqTS2oBHDw?t=361

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I deleted the existing VM and Cloud service and started again - all worked fine out of the box this time.

How annoying! The only thing I did notice was that before my cloud service had the same name as my VM - this time they had different names so that might have been what was causing the issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 34):

1. **Add endpoints for port 80 (http) and port 443 (https) to the VM in the Azure portal** (tip: this can be automated with powershell or the Azure cli).
2. Remote desktop to the machine. Open the Windows firewall control panel and **allow traffic to port 80 (http) and port 443 (https) or just turn it off** ... **the firewall is ON by default** (tip: can also be scripted through the VM agent / powershell).
3. Go to the Azure portal and find the cloudapp.net subdomain for your VM (actually the cloud service) your VM is running under. Try accessing the site with that domain. If that doesn't work, try browsing to http://localhost on the server (remote desktop) to make sure IIS works and troubleshoot from there.
4. Modify the DNS records of your custom domain to use a CNAME to the .cloudapp.net domain. If you need A records make sure to use the public IP of the cloud service (just ping the .cloudapp.net domain to find it or look in the Azure portal).

You might want to look into Azure Websites or Azure Cloud Services (web roles). Those are a lot easier to manage and a lot cheaper. They still offer most of the functionality.

Comment: How do you "Add endpoints"?

Answer (score 26):

What fixed the issue for me was to go into the Azure Portal, browse to 'Network Security Groups', select the VM and then create an inbound rule to allow traffic to port 80.

Note: Also ensure that the inbound rule to port 80 is added and enabled on the actual VM.

Comment: how to get in the "network security groups", is that the "virtual network"?

Comment: 1. Log into your Microsoft Azure portal.
2. On the main menu located on the left hand of the screen locate 'Browse >'.
3. Type 'Network Security Group' in the 'Filter' and hit enter.
4. Select your resource.
5. In the 'Settings' select 'Inbound security rules'.
6. Create rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This resolved the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the newer VMs and pre-configured setups (2015+), it's possible your setup is using an azure asset called `"Public IP"`. If so, you can set a custom DNS name label in it, inside `"Configuration"`. Note that this name will consider any type of region used when creating the VM (e.g. my-site.brazilsouth.cloudapp.azure.com).

It's good to remember that for testing purposes, it still suffices to use the value of the public IP that is randomly designated to you.

Answer (score 0):

The VMs are actually accessed via a Cloud Service (well they are for me). Azure created a Cloud Service automatically to be the scaling engine/load balancer on the front of the VM. I have to connect to the web site via that cloud service, not the VM directly.

Comment: Yes, I have a cloud service and when I look at that in the management portal my VM is sitting under that - when I try and access the url for the cloud service (http://rtcservicestest.cloudapp.net/) which is the same as the VM's dns I get a could not connect error.

Comment: The only other setting I have is the endpoint with a public and private port of 443 (in your case, you seem to have said that you are using 80). Can you see this in the management console under endpoints against the VM?

Comment: Otherwise, the only other things are more basic like is the IP that rtcservicestest points to definitely correct (no DNS/update/TTL issues) and how have you got the bindings set up in IIS on the VM? Naturally accessing it locally behaves somewhat differently than remotely, especially if it connects with localhost rather than rtcservicestest.cloudapp.net.

Comment: Hi, 

Yes, interesting, I've added port 443 as an endpoint for https. I've checked the bindings in IIS and the default website is bound of port 80 fine. 

I can access it locally using the internal IP address but not the DNS or PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS. 

I assuming I've missed some setting in linking the VM to the cloud service somehow but I can't for the life of me find out what it is....

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how they are linked. Azure created the cloud service for me when I created the VM. They both show the same public ip address but only the VM has a private IP. They both also show the same DNS name. The only other thing I can think is if you have multiple cloud services and/or VMs, are you definitely looking at the correct pair that match IPs? Otherwise, if you have mucked around with stuff, it might be easier to create a new VM with the default IIS web site and see if you can get that to work before re-deploying?

Comment: If only I had mucked about with stuff -this is pretty much straight out of the box! 

Ah well, Ill have a go at starting again from scratch while gently whispering about my love for Microsoft and how easy they have made my life over the years under my breath while rocking back and forwards ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you were using the internal IP rather than the external IP.

The sites have to use the internal IP address in the bindings section of IIS. However, in your dns you will need to use the external IP. This is presumably since the 'internal IP' is just a virtual one that Azure uses to map traffic from the external network to the VM's inside azure.

You should find both the internal and external IP's are visible on the VM's desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Switch off TLS 1.3 in the Registry Editor.
This is what worked for me as of writing this in Mar 2021.